# Command executed in SSH terminal displays extra line contents

Tags: perl, ssh

Using Net::SSH::Expect perl module I tried to connect to the server and connection is success. But when its executing the command in connected server and displaying output in current window it displays extra line of output.

Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use Net::SSH::Expect;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
    host => 'hostip', #deb-2-scripting ip
    user => 'user',
    password => 'password',
    raw_pty => 1
);

$ssh->run_ssh() or die "SSH process couldn't start: $!";


$ssh->waitfor('password: ');

$ssh->send("password");

$ssh->exec("stty -echo");

my $hostname = $ssh->exec('hostname');
print "HOST:$hostname\n";

$ssh->close();
```

And output is below:

```
[vinod@deb-3-serv1 TEST_DIR]$ perl test_ssh.pl
HOST:deb-2-scripting
[user@deb-2-scripting(Host) ~]$
```

I wanted output should be displayed like below when I execute `test_ssh.pl`

`HOST:deb-2-scripting`

and last line shouldn't be printed which shows in my output result above.

Comment: Why do you have a new line `\n` at the end of the print?

Comment: I have some more values to be fetched. So differentiate that I have put a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `no_terminal => 1` option to the constructor.

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
    host => 'hostip', #deb-2-scripting ip
    user => 'user',
    password => 'password',
    raw_pty => 1,
    no_terminal => 1,
);
```

That will prevent the ssh server from allocating a pseudo-tty, and the remote shell should not print a prompt when not running in a tty.