# Connecting to server using Net::SSH::Expect status

Tags: perl, ssh

Using Net::SSH::Expect Perl module I want to connect to the server.

Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use Net::SSH::Expect;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
    host => 'hostip', #deb-2-scripting ip
    user => 'user',
    password => 'password',
    raw_pty => 1
);

..
..
..
$ssh->close();
```

Once I create a $ssh object, I wanted to check whether the connection to SSH is Success or not.

How to achieve this? Do we have any method in Net::SSH::Expect which will return a Boolean value if connection is Success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for [`Net::SSH::Expect::new()`](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-SSH-Expect/source/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pm#L25), you'll see that it doesn't actually create a connection. It simply creates an object with all of the relevant attributes so that it can make the connection in the future when required.

The actual connection is made when the `login()` method is called. And the documentation contains an example of how to check that has been successful.

```
# 2) logon to the SSH server using those credentials.
# test the login output to make sure we had success
my $login_output = $ssh->login();
if ($login_output !~ /Welcome/) {
    die "Login has failed. Login output was $login_output";
}
```

Comment: If I use the above mentioned condition I am not getting any values in ```$login_output``` variable. Because I have made ```no_terminal => 1,``` while creating ```$ssh``` object. Since I don't want anything to be printed in my output window (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511768). If I make it ```no_terminal => 0,``` I am getting the values on ```$login_output```. But the previous question which I asked will not satisfy.